# How to get the last element from a shared preferences file in android studio?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I have stored multiple keys as numbers from "1". How can i retrieve the last element stored in shared preference file?

Comment: What had you tried? Itsl looks easy getall, convert keys to integers, sort, get last...  It would be even easier to store it in some other key

Answer (score 0):

Save it in a SQLlite database and then query for the key with highest number. Its better than use shared prefs for that.

Good luck